# Logging with python/celery/rabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm looking for the best way to keep track of my workers and queues and I'm looking into logging.

I've seen examples in the [celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) that suggests setting up logging as follows:

```html
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    return x + y
```

Where does the logging file go? Also what information is stored in the log file? Is it just information that is contained in the logger.info function?

Does the logfile store the results returned by the workers, or is that separate?

Answer (score 3):

**Where does the logging file go?**

As I can see you don't have any `FileHandlers`. It means logger write messages to console.

Let's check it. Here example of tasks.py:

```
# celery 4.0.2
@celery.task(name='add')
def add(x, y):
    logger.info('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
    return x + y


app = celery.Celery(
    __name__,
    broker='redis://localhost:6379/0',
    backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',
)

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # run task each 2 seconds
    'add-every-2-seconds': {
        'task': 'add',
        'schedule': 2.0,
        'args': (1, 2)
    },
}
```

Run Celery(`celery worker -A tasks.app --loglevel=info --beat`) and check console. You will see something like that:

```
[2017-04-08 18:18:55,924: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task add-every-2-seconds (add)
[2017-04-08 18:18:55,930: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: add[44a6877c-84a2-4a26-815e-1f637fdf9c0c]  
[2017-04-08 18:18:55,932: INFO/PoolWorker-2] add[44a6877c-84a2-4a26-815e-1f637fdf9c0c]: Adding 1 + 2
[2017-04-08 18:18:55,934: INFO/PoolWorker-2] Task add[44a6877c-84a2-4a26-815e-1f637fdf9c0c] succeeded in 0.00191404699945s: 3
[2017-04-08 18:18:57,924: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task add-every-2-seconds (add)
[2017-04-08 18:18:57,928: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: add[c386d360-57d3-4352-8a89-f86bb2376e4e]  
[2017-04-08 18:18:57,930: INFO/PoolWorker-3] add[c386d360-57d3-4352-8a89-f86bb2376e4e]: Adding 1 + 2
[2017-04-08 18:18:57,931: INFO/PoolWorker-3] Task add[c386d360-57d3-4352-8a89-f86bb2376e4e] succeeded in 0.00146738500007s: 3
```

It means logger works good and write our messages. Now let's try to add `FileHandler` for our tasks:

```
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
task_handler = FileHandler('task.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

task_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(task_handler)
```

Run Celery and check folder where stored `tasks.py`. You should see new file(`tasks.log`). Example of content:

```
2017-04-08 18:35:02,052 - tasks - INFO - Adding 1 + 2
...
```

**Does the logfile store the results returned by the workers?**

By default information just print to console. But you can register specific loggers, handlers and customize behavior using [signals](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html), custom Task/Loader class.

Also you can set `-f LOGFILE, --logfile=LOGFILE` argument when run `Celery`.

Hope this helps.